# In a grid with a top resizable row, how can I resize the top row without moving the absolute position of the bottom rows?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Problem**: 
    I have WPF window that is set sizeToContent on height. It has one child (grid) with following row defs:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Name="QueueHeight" Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    <RowDefinition Name="PlayedHeight" Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Row 2 is a static row that will always be 30 pixels and contains main UI.

Resizing the contents row 3 results in window expanding down and row 2 staying put
Resizing the contents row 1 results in window also expanding down and row 2 moving down as well.

**Question**: What can I do so that resizing the contents of row 1 results in row 2 staying in the same place (akin to row 3)? Since this has to be done with animations, I can't just use w.Top = w.Top + resize

**Attempted solutions**: 
    Animated w.Top property and move down needed amount. Results in extremely jittery animation that looks like shit.

Edit: Clarified that I was resizing the contents, not the rows themselves.

Comment: If you resize the first row, how can the second one stay in place? Does this mean that the content of the first row will be cut off? What will happen to the window and the third row in this case?

Comment: Don't change the RowDefiniton height. Leave it constant and change the height of the UI element in row 1 and row 2.

Comment: @vesan: I basically want the first row to grow up instead of down when resizing.

Comment: @Anand: That's what I already do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by simply using Popups instead of grids. They solved all of my issues and simplified my code since a lot of the things I was doing with the grids before, was already done in the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, without any pictures or further description I had to make some wild assumptions about what you really want, so this might be all wrong.

However, if you want an element to grow upwards, I assume that there is some space for it to grow. So, I imagine that you have a situation like this:

[image: Window]

If that is the case and if you want the growth to be done using an animation, it can be achieved using the following XAML: Note that the element that grows up is not a part of the "bottom" grid, as you had it (because it's quite difficult to have it grow outside of the grid). Instead, it is aligned to the bottom of the "top" grid (here's assuming that you have one, of course), and overlaps the "background" element that is already there.

Well, without further ado, here's the XAML. Hope it helps (Window element omitted).

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="GrowStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TopContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                         To="80" Duration="0:0:1"></DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ShrinkStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TopContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                         To="25" Duration="0:0:1"></DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="AliceBlue">
        Top background
    </Label>

    <Label Name="TopContent" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightYellow" Height="25">
        Top Content
    </Label>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightCyan">
            Menu
        </Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="MistyRose">
            Content
        </Label>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,30" Content="Grow" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource GrowStoryboard}"></BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,60" Content="Shrink" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShrinkStoryboard}"></BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I really appreciate your help but I just got home and solved my problem by switching to the PopUp class instead of using grids. I do appreciate the time you took to put into this, and I'll definitely save it for future reference.

Thank you!